# How can I change the selected option in select atribute using the php value that i have?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want my select atribute to change it's selected option depending on php $choice. For example if I chose FOOD ASC (it's option 1) i want to make it selected after i press the button with name "sortbutton"

```
if(isset($_POST['sortbutton']))// if button pressed
{
    $choice = $_POST['sort_select'];
    if($choice == 0){...there was some code //if selected option == 0
        $qr_result = mysqli_query($db, "Select * 
                                        from `menu` 
                                        WHERE id>0 
                                        ORDER BY price ASC")
            or die(mysqli_error());

        echo '<table class="tam" style = "position:fixed; top: 110px;">'; //table
        echo '<td>' . 'Блюдо' . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . 'Состав' . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . 'Цена' . '</td>';
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($qr_result)){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $data['product'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $data['consistency'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $data['price'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>'; //outputing database
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="sorti">
        <select name="sort_select" >
            <option value="0" name = "value1">PRICE ASC</option>
            <option value="1" name = "value2">PRICE DESC</option>
            <option value="2" name = "value3">NAME ASC</option>
            <option value="3" name = "value4">NAME DESC </option>
        </select>
        <button name = "sortbutton">Show menu</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `WHERE id>0` is basically an Oxymoron. the `id` assuming it is AutoIncrement will always be greater than zero

Comment: Your code does not generate anything like the HTML you show

Comment: it's an html that is set as default on site

Comment: The `<div>` inside the form block is not closed

Comment: actually it's not full code and div is closed, but thank you. Can you please answer my question?

Comment: i think you are mixing php and javascript. PHP would be usefull for your task if you have the value on page load. To change the value while the page is rendered you need to use javascript

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: PS `<option>` elements do not have a `name` attribute. That could be why odd things are happening

Comment: nothing happens @RiggsFolly, there are no Errors. I am asking about how to do one thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="sorti">
        <select name="sort_select" >
            <option value="0" name = "value1" <?php echo $choice== 0?"selected":"";  ?>>PRICE ASC</option>
            <option value="1" name = "value2" <?php echo $choice== 1?"selected":"";  ?> >PRICE DESC</option>
            <option value="2" name = "value3" <?php echo $choice== 2?"selected":"";  ?> >NAME ASC</option>
            <option value="3" name = "value4" <?php echo $choice== 3?"selected":"";  ?> >NAME DESC </option>
        </select>
        <button name = "sortbutton">Show menu</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

I assume , the next page renders the same form again doing above on the html should work.
I would probably want to write this better but setting selected on the option is a solution you should go for

Comment: I assume you meant `$choice == 1`, `== 2`, etc instead of `== 0` for all options?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help to solve this problem

Comment: UPDATE: with @WOUNDEDStevenJones help it worked the way I wanted it to work, thanks

Comment: ya , i thought i had put it properly , edited it now to make it proper

Comment: You also might want to remove the `name` attributes from the `<option>` tags

Answer (score 0):

The `option` element does not have a `name` attribute, that should be removed, the name of the dropdown selection is of course the name used in the `<select name="sort_select">` element then a simple ternary test, testing the value of `$choice`
will set the selected attribute for you like this

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="sort_select">
        <option value="0" <?php echo $choice==0 ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>PRICE ASC</option>
        <option value="1" <?php echo $choice==1 ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>PRICE DESC</option>
        <option value="2" <?php echo $choice==2 ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>NAME ASC</option>
        <option value="3" <?php echo $choice==2 ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>NAME DESC </option>
    </select>
    <button name="sortbutton">Show menu</button>
</form>
```